# Why is this DataTrigger not working after a PropertyChanged?

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, datatrigger

The following triggers work almost as expected:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Value="True" Property="IsSelected">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Trigger>
    <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InUseConverter}}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="OrangeRed" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

After loading the view, the colors are correct.
Then I execute an async taks en when it has finished I give the propertychanged on the object that has the binding to my datagrid-row.
But why is the DataTrigger not fired (I have to refresh the view to see the effect)?

EDIT:
My problem is that I don't now which property I have to give the `PropertyChanged`.
Some details about the datagrid (`Projects` is an `ObservableCollection`):

```
DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding Project}" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
```

The property of object `Project` that the binding must use is:
`Project.Variants[0].InUse`

I tried also the triggers:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Variants[0].InUse, Converter={StaticResource NotNullConverter}}">

<DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource InUseConverter}}">
```

In the view model I have tried after `Project.Variants[0].InUse = null;`:

```
Project.OnPropertyChanged("InUse");
Project.Variants[0].OnPropertyChanged("InUse");
raisePropertyChanged("Project.Variants[0].InUse");
raisePropertyChanged("Variants[0].InUse");
raisePropertyChanged("Projects");
raisePropertyChanged("Project");
raisePropertyChanged("InUse");
```

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger` is for when you want to pass value from view to view model. In this case you want to get value and for that, to happen automatically, your class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Does it?

Comment: {Binding Path=. UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InUseConverter}}

Comment: @Gerard anyway in your case you don't specify `Path` so it will not trigger on any specific property change from your view model. Do you use few properties from your view model in that converter? Maybe it's worth changing that to `MultiBinding`.

Comment: @eran otzap: leaving out Path is the same as Path=.

Comment: @dkozl: the specific property is used in the `InUseConverter` code, I just want the databound item of the row to be triggered

Comment: @Gerard but it won't trigger on anything. No `PropertyChanged` callback from within that view model (row) will trigger foreground change beacause it doesn't change the object itself. Do I understand well that you expect your trigger to work on property(ies) change that are used by `InUseConverter`?

Comment: @Gerard try it out , when using a converter you need to define the path even if the path is the DataContext itself , when not using a converter you would be correct .

Comment: @eran otzap, dkozi: see my edit, I tried Path and I am aware that the object itself does not change.

Comment: Are you using ObservableCollection for Projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last it works using:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Variants[0].InUse, Converter={StaticResource NotNullConverter}}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="OrangeRed" />
</DataTrigger>

Project.Variants[0].OnPropertyChanged("InUse");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Foreground property in your style to change it dynamically at runtime

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Value="True" Property="IsSelected">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Trigger>
    <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InUseConverter}}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="OrangeRed" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```